# Logout user on wrong encryption key in Realm

Tags: android, encryption, realm, local-storage, realm-migration

I am using a [Realm database](https://blog.realm.io/realm-for-android) in my Android App. The data needs to be encrypted and I am using `Realm`'s encryption. They key is coming from server and then is stored on device, but is encrypted using user PIN.

I want to logout user if - by any means - the key is tempered. I am using `ParentActivity` class for some general initialization and tried to do it inside `onCreate` like below,

```
private void initRealm() {
    try {
        if(MyApplication.getInstance().isRelamInitialized)
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        deleteAllAndLogout();
    }

}
```

And the `deleteAllAndLogout` looks like below,

```
public void deleteAllAndLogout() {
    session.logoutUser();
    session.removeFbData();
    RealmManager.deleteAll(realm);
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

**Problem**

- `Realm` is not initialized yet, then how is it supposed to clear data without `realm` being initialized?
- When I tested it, it kept starting `LoginActivity` again and again and never stopped.

I am initializing `Realm` in `Application` class.

```
public void initRealm() {
    String encryptedKey = new Session(getApplicationContext()).getStringForKey(Session.mainEncryptedKeyForEncryption);
    String key = new Cipher(getApplicationContext()).decrypt(encryptedKey);

    Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
    config = new RealmConfiguration
            .Builder()
            .encryptionKey(key.getBytes())
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .name(DB_NAME)
            .schemaVersion(DB_VERSION)
            .build();

    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    isRelamInitialized = true;

}
```

**Question**

How and where can I delete all local data and logout user when `Realm` is not decrypted correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Realm will throw a `RealmFileException` if you try to open a Realm file with the wrong encryption key.

So you would need to wrap all calls to `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`, catch the exception and log the user out if it happens.